# Performing reptitive statements against a sqlite3 database

Tags: xcode, sqlite

The method below runs against a sqlite3 database. It's intended to fetch all of the primary keys for records matching each of the foreign keys in the array it's passed as a parameter (flds).

```
- (NSArray*) columnPrimaryKeysForFields:(NSArray*)flds
{
    NSMutableArray* retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString* query = @"SELECT ID FROM Pages WHERE FieldID = ? ORDER BY ID";
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        for (NSNumber* fieldID in flds)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, (int)[fieldID longValue]);

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                [retval addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)]];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"SQL PREPARE columnPrimaryKeysForFields failed");
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:retval];
}
```

In the database, there are multiple records containing each of the keys in flds. When the method executes it fetches all of the records containing first key in flds, but only the first record containing each of the subsequent keys in flds. I can't figure out why the first key in flds fetches the correct number of records but the subsequent keys do not.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [sqlite3_reset](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) after the last `step` call.